# PHP strpos not returning true when the items match

Tags: php

This is going to sound really simple but I can't understand why its not working.

I am checking that a string matches something to enable some texts to be sent.

The string that is returned is: `Delivered to UPS Access Point™ location and awaiting customer pickup.`

And this is the statement I am using to check for it

```
if(strpos(strtolower($step->status), "delivered to ups access point")) {

}
```

Currently that if statement is returning false when I would expect it to be true

Any ideas

Answer (score 4):

You are treating the strpos as if it's a boolean, which is it not. It returns the position of the string which would be 0, and translates to false.

So compare against not false (not found) or >= 0 (found), type is important.

Example:

```
    $data = "Delivered to UPS Access Point™ location and awaiting customer pickup.";
    if(strpos(strtolower($data), "delivered to ups access point") !== false) {
     echo 'Found!';
    }
```

Comment: Perfect thanks, completely forgot that this returns like that

Comment: Everyone has moments like that ;)

Comment: `strpos` returns `false` if not found, not `-1`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
$step->status = "Delivered to UPS Access Point™ location and awaiting customer pickup.";
if(strpos(strtolower($step->status), "delivered to ups access point") !== false) {
    echo "String matches";
}
else {
    echo "String not matches";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

strpos is return index of your second argument. In your case "delivered to ups access point" is starting point mean 0th position. 0 mean false.